# Running local HTML file with http protocol

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html file, when I click it, browser window pops up with `file:///c:/myhtml.html`. How can I run this file with http protocol scheme, so that the url would be like `http://localhost/myhtml`?

I don't want to setup a heavyweight webserver. Is there any nice and neat solution for this?

Why I want to do this is, to test my html file under http protocol instead of `file:///` protocol on which browsers restrict some functionality.

Comment: you need a web server running on your machine, e.g. Apache https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: What OS are you using? If you have python, a quick solution is ```python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000```

Comment: I need light weight solutions friends lighter than apache

Comment: Please see my answer. I couldn't recommend nginx enough. Very easy to configure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have **Python** installed, type ...

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

If you have **Ruby** installed, type ...

`ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8000`

... in your cmd.exe or Terminal.app

This will launch a very simple http-server that serves your current folder as a http-context.

**Resulting URL**

http://localhost:8000

Comment: If you get `No module named SimpleHTTPServer` error while executing the above command you can try `python -m http.server 8000`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you look at [nginx](http://nginx.org/). It's pretty lightweight and easy to configure. It's also well [documented](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) (look at the serving static content section for what you've requested).

There are a lot of tutorials online showing how to get started. You can create a simple web server without much effort.

Comment: Good shout, nginx also runs very well on a rasPi